# Salesforce Chatter: Can I use apex trigger and the Chatter API to auto - subscribe sales team members to opportunity

Tags: chatter

Can I use apex trigger and the Chatter API to auto - subscribe sales team members to opportunity.

Also, Please explain a scenario if you have worked on any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert a [EntitySubscription](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_entitysubscription.htm) record for each sales rep.

> [EntitySubscription] represents a subscription for a user following a record or another
>   user. A user can subscribe to a record or to another user. Changes to
>   the record and updates from the users are displayed in the Chatter
>   feed on the user's home page, which is a useful way to stay up-to-date
>   with other users and with changes made to records in Salesforce. Feeds
>   are available in API version 18.0 and later.

Therefore you should create a new after insert trigger. The trigger has to populate the field parentID with the opportunity Id and the subscriber Id with the user Id.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Chatter API (classes in the ConnectApi namespace) in the trigger:

```
ChatterUsers.ConnectApi.Subscription subscriptionToRecord = ConnectApi.ChatterUsers.follow(Network.getNetworkId(), 'me', '006D000000CtwLa');
```

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterUsers_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterUsers_follow